Pulling multiple Subnets out of data block and making a locals list fails
I am attempting to create a web app with vnet access restrictions.  To do this I need to pass  a name (which i'd like to be the subnet, the subnet id, and the priority.  I have a list of subnets i gathers from a data block using the below:
data "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = var.np_vnet1
  resource_group_name = var.np_vnet_rg
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "np-vnet1-subnets" {
  for_each             = toset(data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.subnets)
  name                 = each.value
  virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.resource_group_name
}

From the data.azurerm_subnet.np-vnet1-subnets i am trying to build the format in my locals file to be passed dynamically to the azurerm_windows_web_app resource.
locals {
subnet_restrictions = [
    for idx, subnet in [data.azurerm_subnet.np-vnet1-subnets] : {
      name                      = subnet.name
      virtual_network_subnet_id = subnet.id
      priority                  = idx + 100
    }
  ]
}

This locals block will be passed dynamically for the ip_restrictions in the web app
dynamic "ip_restriction" {
      for_each = local.subnet_restrictions
      content {
        name                      = ip_restriction.value["name"]
        virtual_network_subnet_id = ip_restriction.value["virtual_network_subnet_id"]
        priority                  = ip_restriction.value["priority"]
        action                    = "Allow"
      }
    }

However I keep getting errors on the name and id on the locals block.  Stating the object does not have the attribute of name or id
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on locals.tf line 29, in locals:
│   29:       name                      = subnet.name
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "name".
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on locals.tf line 30, in locals:
│   30:       virtual_network_subnet_id = subnet.id
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "id".

I am not sure what I may be doing wrong, when attempting to build the list of subnets out.

The first thing that comes to mind is that [data.azurerm_subnet.np-vnet1-subnets] should be just data.azurerm_subnet.np-vnet1-subnets.

What is the terraform version you are using. @NickP

I have modified the locals block as given below. Have you verified it. @NickP

The error is occurring with the locals block while looping the list of subnets. Modify it as shown below to fix the code and also Thanks @Marko E for pointing in the similar direction.
locals {
subnet_restrictions = [
    for idx, subnet in data.azurerm_subnet.np_vnetsubnet : {
      name                      = subnet.name
      virtual_network_subnet_id = subnet.id
      priority                  = tonumber(idx) + 100 //Or directlt set it to a constant
    }
  ]
}

Modified Terraform code:
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = "xxxx"
}
data "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "azurecloudservice3VNet"
  resource_group_name = "Jahnavi"
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "np_vnetsubnet" {
  for_each             = toset(data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.subnets)
  name                 = each.value
  virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.resource_group_name
}
locals {
subnet_restrictions = [
    for idx, subnet in data.azurerm_subnet.np_vnetsubnet : {
      name                      = subnet.name
      virtual_network_subnet_id = subnet.id
      priority                  = tonumber(idx) + 100 //Or directlt set it to a constant
    }
  ]
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "ipresources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "ipexample"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  sku_name            = "P1v2"
  os_type             = "Windows"
}

resource "azurerm_windows_web_app" "example" {
  name                = "ipappjah"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_service_plan.example.location
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.example.id

  site_config {
  dynamic "ip_restriction" {
      for_each = local.subnet_restrictions
      content {
        name                      = ip_restriction.value["name"]
        virtual_network_subnet_id = ip_restriction.value["virtual_network_subnet_id"]
        priority                  = ip_restriction.value["priority"]
        action                    = "Allow"
      }
    }
  }
}

Deployment succeeded:



Reference for terraform registry template.

this worked! thank you!
